# MS Sql2000 and "scheme"

Tags: sql-server, schema

I've run to a problem in which I'm not sure where to look or how to fix it.
The problem is the following.
We have a site with a sql2000database.
A backup from this was restored to create a development enviroment.
Some of the store procedures are named [owner].name (owner is not dbo and I would want to keep the same structure in both live and development enviroment)

When I try to run those store procedures without specifing the owners name I get a "could not find store procedure" error. (using the owners credentials)

But I create a new user, and a new store procedure where this new users is the owner. And then login with the new user. Then I can find the store procedure by its name.

Example:

Owner = Daniel
SPTest = store procedure (name Daniel.SPTest)

Login as Daniel,
exec SPTest = store procedure not found <-- what is wrong here?

Create a new user and store procedure in the database
Owner New User
SPTest2 = Store procedure (name New User.SPTest2)
Login as New User
exec SPTest2 = runs procedure

I've tried to delete the user Daniel, then creating a new user with the username Daniel. But I still recieved the same error. Is there any other table where this kind of mapping is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your user 'Daniel' on the server (not just for that database, but in security objects for the server) then run:

```
USE YOUR_SQL_2000DB
sp_change_users_login 'auto_fix', 'Daniel'
```

The problem (most likely) is that your database is not viewing your new 'Daniel' as the same user as the old 'Daniel'.  That system sproc should repair that.

Comment: That would probably fix the problem. I did something similar to fix the issue though. I created a new user, changed the ownership to the new user. Then deleted the old one, created a new user with the old name and then changed back the ownership and then it worked.  But your solution is probably the right way to go :)